# Play youtube video when cell selcted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, uitableview

It's possible to play a youtube video when a cell from table view is selected ?

This is how i load a video on my cell :

```
 NSString * aux=[[stories objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"url"];
 NSString *   videoHTML =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"<iframe type=\"text/html\" width=\"100\" height=\"80\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>",aux] ;
 [cell.WEB loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];
```

And it works when i select the video , but i want to play it when i select the cell , not only the video .

Comment: This wasn't possible with UIWebView, but you might take a look at WKWebView.